# Neo4j - WHERE vs {property}?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to understand what the difference is between

```
MATCH (a) WHERE a.name='Peter' RETURN a
```

and

```
MATCH (a {name:'Peter'}) RETURN a
```

both return the same results. Is one faster or cheaper in computing cycles? Which is the preferred approach?

Comment: They're the same.  The `(a {name:'Peter'})` is just for convenience / style

Comment: But actuall you should use a label, like `:Person` in both places.